# ERRORS: Trying to install truffle to terminal

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm completely new at this and keep getting an error message trying to install truffle. If I need to delete or add anything please explain in detail how to do so.

> ```
> npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
> npm ERR! syscall rename
> npm ERR! path /Users/paulbrady/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle
> npm ERR! dest /Users/paulbrady/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.truffle-f258BAu1
> npm ERR! errno -66
> npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/paulbrady/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle' -> '/Users/paulbrady/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.truffle-f258BAu1'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/paulbrady/.npm/_logs/2021-05-19T09_32_00_700Z-debug.log
> paulbrady@Pauls-MacBook-Air ~ %
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and this is how I solved it

1. Remove the already installed truffle

```
sudo -i
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
rm -r truffle .truffle_
```

2. Make sure Ganache is running first before reinstalling truffle again
3. Install Truffle: `npm install -g truffle`